# Java Htmlunit - disable anchor - How to click?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to log at this webiste:

https://recordings.integralnet.pl/admin-panel/login?lang=en

I put login & pass, but I can't click at "Submit" button. It's disabled until both text inputs are empty. I have no more idea, how to enable it. Can Yoy help me?

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    try {
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://recordings.integralnet.pl/admin-panel/login?lang=en");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
        System.out.println(page.asXml());

        DomElement loginElement = page.getElementById("textfield-1010-inputEl");
        loginElement.setAttribute("j_username", "myLogin");

        DomElement passwordElement = page.getElementById("login-form-password-inputEl");
        passwordElement.setAttribute("j_password", "myPassword");

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);

        DomElement submitElement = page.getElementById("button-1012");
        submitElement.removeAttribute("disabled");

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
        HtmlPage clickedPage = submitElement.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        System.out.println(clickedPage.asXml());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    try {
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://recordings.integralnet.pl/admin-panel/login?lang=en");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
        System.out.println(page.asXml());

        HtmlTextInput loginElement = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("textfield-1010-inputEl");
        loginElement.type("myLogin");
        HtmlPasswordInput passwordElement = (HtmlPasswordInput) page.getElementById("login-form-password-inputEl");
        passwordElement.type("myPass");

        DomElement submitElement = page.getElementById("button-1012");

        HtmlPage clickedPage = submitElement.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        System.out.println(clickedPage.asText());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```